# TL-WN823N not working with Ubuntu 17!

Tags: wireless, adapter

i want to install the drivers of this Wireless Adapter TP-LINK **TL-WN823N** (v2) onto a **live Ubuntu 17 USB**.
If it can work on a Ubuntu setup like from a Hard Disk it's almost same as working it with USB. Right.
So i already searched many and there were many tutorial and questionnaire about this topic. But i don't understand shit.
I don't know the correct procedure to install this driver, i am very new to Ubuntu. Perhaps i need more time to figure out my way with Linus Os.
I found two places which give more description on this driver issues.

[Check this Post 1](http://omnine.blogspot.in/2016/09/make-tl-wn823n-work-with-ubuntu-1604-lts.html)

[Check this Post 2](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes)

I already use this Wireless Adapter on to a PC Win7; no problem.
But i cannot get it to use in live Ubuntu 17.
Can someone be kind enough to take some time and show me how can i achieve this.

Here are the results from the terminal:

     `lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2357:0109

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 03f0:7f40 Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 275d:0ba6 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1130:1620 Tenx Technology, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub`

2nd/Feb/2018

Can some give me a heads up. Its really a pain in the ass.
I am not familiar with Ubuntu or Linux console.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb`

Comment: Has anybody come across this problem before.

Comment: It should work in 17.10 with the rtl8xxxu module, any results from terminal for `rfkill list; lsmod | grep rtl`

Comment: I believe it too. Linux OS seems quite fundamentally similar in its driver installation procedure. I uploaded the pdf instruction to install the drivers. **Here is the link**: [link]http://www.mediafire.com/file/l9fmwsi1de4ltmf/Installation%20for%20linux%20driver_RTL.pdf [/link]This the place where i downloaded it from. http://www.tp-link.com/us/download/TL-WN823N.html#Driver

Comment: That link shows it is for kernel 3.10 and older, that will not work in any supported version of Ubuntu.  What kernel do you have?  `uname -r`

Comment: It came ou to be like this.
Hope you can understand.
<code>uname -r
4.10.0-19-generic</code>

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 is no longer supported, so it is recommended that you switch to 16.04 which is supported until 2021, I would not switch to 16.04.2 or higher because of the kernel used, you could also use 17.10 which is supported until August of this year and/or switch from 17.10 when 18.04 is released in April of this year, it will have 5 years of support and your USB wifi should work without installing a driver.  If you decide to use 16.04 search this site for 8192eu and you should find a couple methods to install the driver